# OpenGL/GLFW: Why is the detected mouse position incorrect when using a TV as the primary display for my laptop?

Tags: opengl, glfw

My mouse is connected to my laptop, and my laptop is connected a TV via HDMI. When just using the laptop's screen as the primary display, the position of the mouse is perfect and there is no issue at all showing that it is, and when using Windows (with either the laptop screen OR TV as a display) there is no issue with the mouse - it is **only within my GLFW application, when an external screen is used as the primary display**. I get the position of the mouse using a callback function that returns a vec2, which is set using `glfwSetCursorPosCallback()`, so I am able to view the coordinates of the mouse each frame with `mousePos.x` and `mousePos.y`.

**The specific inaccuracy with the mouse position:**

When the mouse is moved the position that is detected changes, but this detected position does not stop changing when the mouse stops moving. This could be described as having the mouse on ice, so that when it is moved, the position continues to change and it never slows down. So the position is accurate, but it does not correspond to physical movement of the mouse because - as mentioned earlier - I stop moving the mouse, but the position just increases at a constant rate forever.

This can be viewed most obviously when the mouse position is used to move to camera around - the camera just continues rotating even though the mouse is stationary.

Why would using an external display have this effect on the mouse position/movement detection?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it now. For anyone who finds this in the future... use the latest version of GLFW! The particular version I was using (3.1.2) had a problem with `glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_HIDDEN)` which caused the strange movement of the cursor.

This was fixed in the 3.2 update - make sure you're using this one if you encounter this problem!